# Instagram API Workflow with moderation

Tags: api, instagram

All:

I know nothing about the Instagram API, but was asked to develop an Instagram workflow for my company. "Hey, your the programmer right?"

Our managers would like Instagram's of people using our products, but they don't want pictures of our products displayed in an unfavorable light. So, can I, using the Instagram API, create a workflow which does this:

User takes Instagram and adds our hashtag --> Company app filters our tags --> Send to Editorial --> Editorial approves Instagram and posts image.

Does this make sense?

Thanks,
Norm

Answer (score 4):

Norm,

You can subscribe to a feed to get the updates for tags related to your product using the [real time api](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)

I would suggest you store every updates (new photos) in a database and then develop a front end to review and approve the images.

[Here](http://thegregthompson.com/instagram-real-time-api-php/) is a basic example on how to deal with the API in php

Answer (score 1):

yumyum pointed you to a great article that I also used in order to create the exact same system you are aiming for.

The api only returns abount 25 images per call. Included in the return is pagination info with which to make the next call. So I initially iterare through all the images and store the data in my DB.
My client has a front-end where he can see the image and relevant data as well as a checkbox next to each image determining whether or not that image will go 'live' on the actual app.
The client can manually (an button click) check for new images whenever he wants to which initiates the above process again whereby only images not in the DB are added.

One thing to watch out for: you have to watch out for images that have been deleted by the user since they will not be accesible anymore. I use jquery to check for an error on loading the image and if yes delete it from the DB via ajax.